# How do I split on the space-separated math operators here?

Tags: python

I have a user calculator that accepts both numbers and user-defined variables. My plan is to split the statement on a space-delimited operator, e.g. ' + ':

```
import re
query = 'house-width + 3 - y ^ (5 * house length)'
query = re.findall('[+-/*//]|\d+|\D+', query)
print query  # ['house-width + ', '3', ' - y ^ (', '5', ' * house length)']

Expecting:
['house-width', '+', '3', '-', 'y', '^', '(5', '*', 'house length)']
```

Comment: To split on a space, split on a space (which makes the last value in the 'expected' output *wrong*). However, I recommend not splitting on spaces but instead read one token at a time from the start to get a token stream. You could then handle two consecutive identifiers as a compound identifier (although this just seems like a bad language grammar).

Comment: If you could make `house length` into `house-length`, to be consistent with `house-width`, then you could split on spaces.

Comment: @PaulRooney: Unfortunately that isn't possible. There will be a mixture of spaces, hyphens, etc in the variable names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `re.split` with capturing parentheses around the split pattern seems to work fairly effectively. As long as you have the capturing parens in the pattern the patterns you are splitting on are kept in the resulting list:

```
re.split(' ([+-/*^]|//) ', query)
Out[6]: ['house-width', '+', '3', '-', 'y', '^', '(5', '*', 'house length)']
```

(PS: I'm assuming from your original regex you want to catch `//` integer division operators, you can't do that with a single character class, so I've moved that outside the character class as a special case.)