# How do I include the operators in my output when I split my string?

Tags: regex, go

Yesterday I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608951/how-do-i-split-on-the-space-separated-math-operators-here) about splitting a string in python. I've since decided to do this project in Go instead. I have the following:

```
input := "house-width + 3 - y ^ (5 * house length)"
s := regexp.MustCompile(" ([+-/*^]) ").Split(input, -1)
log.Println(s)  //  [house-width 3 y (5 house length)]
```

How do I include the operators in this output? e.g. I'd like the following output:

```
['house-width', '+', '3', '-', 'y', '^', '(5', '*', 'house length)']
```

EDIT:
To clarify I am splitting on the space-separated operators and not just the operator. The operator must have a space on both ends to differentiate it from a dash/hyphen. Please refer to my original python question I linked to for clarification if needed.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to use regex vs strings.Split(input, " ")? http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split

Comment: This `" ([+-/*^]) "` is more functional as `"\s*([+\-/*^])\s*"` and the minus sign must be escaped. Whats the problem in `go`? Does it include the capture in the output array ? Anyway, I'm not sure you should split on spaces, its not really a delimiter.

Comment: @sln the issue is that what I have is not returning the operators. Instead it returns "['house-width' '3' 'y' '(5' 'house length)']" http://play.golang.org/p/B4zCSLWPjz

Comment: I glanced at the docs. Go uses RE2 type expressions that don't do backtracking, nor assertions. And the split looks primitive (couldn't find any info on that). But, it looks like `FindAll()` might be your best bet. You have a dilemma though, <space>+<operator>+<space> can't be used as a delimiter because go's engine doesn't do lookaround assertions, therefore it consumes the last <space> which can't be used as the first <space> if there is an adjacent operator, even if you say this will never happen, there is no provision of constructs to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the operands of your expression using [`regexp.Split()`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.Split) (just as you did) and you can get the operators (the separators) using [`regexp.FindAllString()`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindAllString).

By doing this you will have 2 separate `[]string` slices, you can merge these 2 slices if you want the result in one `[]string` slice.

```
input := "house-width + 3 - y ^ (5 * house length)"

r := regexp.MustCompile(`\s([+\-/*^])\s`)

s1 := r.Split(input, -1)
s2 := r.FindAllString(input, -1)

fmt.Printf("%q\n", s1)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s2)

all := make([]string, len(s1)+len(s2))
for i := range s1 {
    all[i*2] = s1[i]
    if i < len(s2) {
        all[i*2+1] = s2[i]
    }
}
fmt.Printf("%q\n", all)
```

**Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/pzYJwMcLaE)):**

```
["house-width" "3" "y" "(5" "house length)"]
[" + " " - " " ^ " " * "]
["house-width" " + " "3" " - " "y" " ^ " "(5" " * " "house length)"]
```

**Note:**

If you want to trim the spaces from the operators, you can use the [`strings.TrimSpace()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimSpace) function for that:

```
for i, v := range s2 {
    all[i*2+1] = strings.TrimSpace(v)
}
fmt.Printf("%q\n", all)
```

Output:

```
["house-width" "+" "3" "-" "y" "^" "(5" "*" "house length)"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're planing to parse the expression afterwards you'll have to make some changes:

- Include parentheses as lexemes
- You can't have both spaces *and* dashes be valid identifier characters because e.g. `- y` inbetween `3` and `^` would be a valid identifier.

After that's done, you can use use a simple [linear iteration](http://play.golang.org/p/kHXngpFL_O) to lex your string:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    input := `house width + 3 - y ^ (5 * house length)`
    buffr := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    outpt := make([]string, 0)

    for _, r := range input {
        if r == '+' || r == '-' || r == '*' || r == '/' || r == '^' || r == '(' || r == ')' || (r >= '0' && r <= '9') {
            bs := bytes.TrimSpace(buffr.Bytes())
            if len(bs) > 0 {
                outpt = append(outpt, (string)(bs))
            }
            outpt = append(outpt, (string)(r))
            buffr.Reset()
        } else {
            buffr.WriteRune(r)
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", outpt)

}
```

Once lexed, use Dijkstra's [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to build an AST or directly evaluate the expression.

Comment: "You can't have both spaces and dashes" That's why I am splitting on a space-separated operator.

Answer (score 0):

I think FindAll() may be the way to go.

Expanded regex:

```
 \s*                           # Trim preceding whitespace
 (                             # (1 start), Operator/Non-Operator chars
      (?:                           # Cluster group
           \w -                          # word dash
        |  - \w                          # or, dash word
        |  [^+\-/*^]                     # or, a non-operator char
      )+                            # End cluster, do 1 to many times
   |                              # or,
      [+\-/*^]                      # A single simple math operator
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s*                           # Trim trailing whitespace
```

Go code snippet:

http://play.golang.org/p/bHZ21B6Tzi

```
package main

import (
"log"
"regexp"
)
func main() {
    in := []byte("house-width + 3 - y ^ (5 * house length)")
    rr := regexp.MustCompile("\\s*((?:\\w-|-\\w|[^+\\-/*^])+|[+\\-/*^])\\s*")
    s := r.FindAll( in, -1 )
    for _, ss:=range s{
      log.Println(string(ss))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 house-width 
 + 
 3 
 - 
 y 
 ^ 
 (5 
 * 
 house length)
```